# 1 leg armature is controling both legs

Tags: rigging

I am having a problem where the left legs armature is controlling the deformation of both legs at the same time. I thought this was originally a mirroring issue but the arms work perfectly fine. The right legs armature does nothing. I told the program to armature deform with automatic weights. I am a beginner to blender so if you could use screen shots with your answer that would be great.

thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your mesh is mirrored.  You will have to apply the mirror modifier, and you will probably have to redo your weights.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OMG thank you so much. i feel like an idiot. in the video i was using (admittedly it was an older version 2.78) i never realized that he used a shortcut to apply the mirror after the mesh was done and because it was mirrored i never realized i had to do anything else.

Comment: That's Great,  I remember when I was a beginner that I had that same problem all the time.  i didn't even know how to apply the mirror modifier.  Then I thought, "there really should just be a **apply** button on the mirror modifier.  I looked and there it was.  HaHa.